# Python iterators. Initialize state variables in __init__ or __iter__?

Tags: python, iterator

I'm fairly new to Python and was just looking at some examples of defining iterator objects.

The example I looked at was :

```
class fibit:  # iterate through fibonacci sequence from 0,1...n<=max
    def __init__(self, max):       
        self.max = max

   def __iter__(self):
        self.a = 0
        self.b = 1
        return self

   def next(self):
        fib = self.a
        if fib > self.max:
            raise StopIteration
        self.a, self.b = self.b, self.a + self.b
        return fib
```

But if I move the initialization of self.a and self.b from **iter** to **init** it seems (to my simple understanding) to work exactly the same way.

```
class fibit:  # iterate through fibonacci sequence from 0,1...n<=max
    def __init__(self, max):
        self.a = 0
        self.b = 1        
        self.max = max

   def __iter__(self):
        return self

   def next(self):
        fib = self.a
        if fib > self.max:
            raise StopIteration
        self.a, self.b = self.b, self.a + self.b
        return fib
```

So which one is the recommended way to do this?

Thanks. :)

Answer (score 11):

Initialization should be done in `__init__`. That's why it's there.

Iterator objects in Python are canonically "use once" - once you've iterated through an iterator, it's not expected that you'll be able to iterate through it again.

Thus, it makes no sense to re-initialize the values if you try to iterate over the object again. To illustrate this, I've extended your code a bit:

```
class fibit_iter:  # iterate through fibonacci sequence from 0,1...n<=max
    def __init__(self, max):
        self.max = max

    def __iter__(self):
        self.a = 0
        self.b = 1
        return self

    def next(self):
        fib = self.a
        if fib > self.max:
            raise StopIteration
        self.a, self.b = self.b, self.a + self.b
        return fib

class fibit_init:  # iterate through fibonacci sequence from 0,1...n<=max
    def __init__(self, max):
        self.a = 0
        self.b = 1
        self.max = max

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def next(self):
        fib = self.a
        if fib > self.max:
            raise StopIteration
        self.a, self.b = self.b, self.a + self.b
        return fib

iter_iter = fibit_iter(10)
iter_init = fibit_init(10)

print "iter_iter"

for item in iter_iter:
    print item
    break

for item in iter_iter:
    print item
    break

print "iter_init"

for item in iter_init:
    print item
    break

for item in iter_init:
    print item
    break
```

Essentially, I create an object from your init version, and an object from your iter version. Then I try partial iterating over both of them twice. Notice how you get different results:

```
iter_iter
0
0
iter_init
0
1
```

Comment: So are you saying that the second example above would be the preferred way of doing it?

Comment: Amber, thank you very much for that code and explanation. It makes the subtle differences in their operation much clearer to me. :)

Answer (score 2):

`__init__` is used when initializing an instance of a class. It is used to set attributes of a classinstance.

`__iter__` is used to define behaviour for a class which is iterable (returns an interator).

@mgilson - `__iter__` generally returns an Iterator which is different than a list (the type() is physicaly different) in that Iterators yield (destructively consume) values.

Try calling the `__iter__()` method of an xrange instance and attempt to cycle through the values multiple times.

```
 >>> foo = xrange(5)
 >>> bar = a.__iter__()
 >>> bar.next()
 0
 >>> bar.next()
 1
 >>> list(bar)
 [2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: Thanks. Like I said I'm really new to this, the above example was the very first iterator object that I've looked at. At this point I'm struggling to see what code would ever be needed in __iter__, other than "return self"

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on what you want your iterator to do.  If you have a good reason to iterate through your iterator multiple times, getting the same result each time, then put the initialization in `__iter__`; however, this should be the exception and not the norm; as well-behaved iterators should continue to `raise StopIteration` when exhausted, not restart the sequence.  In fact:  an iterator that returns more values after a `StopIteration` is raised is [considered broken](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#iterator-types) (although this is more a warning to be careful how you use it).

So, to reiterate:

- for a standard iterator, put your initialization in `__init__`
- for custom/repeat behavior, put your initialization in `__iter__`